# Required permissions are not granted. At least one of these permissions must be granted: Users

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, authorization, aspnetboilerplate

I'm trying to implement a file upload in an ASP.NET Boilerplate project.
This is my code:

**Index.cshtml**:

```html
<form asp-controller="Backlog" asp-action="Upload_Image" method="post"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <input type="file" name="file" />

  <button type="submit">Upload Image</button>

</form>
```

**BacklogController.cs**:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Abp.Application.Services.Dto;
using Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using MyProject.Authorization;
using MyProject.Controllers;
using MyProject.Users;
using MyProject.Web.Models.Backlog;
using MyProject.Users.Dto;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MyProject.Backlog;

namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
    [AbpMvcAuthorize(PermissionNames.Pages_Backlog)]
    public class BacklogController : MyProjectControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IUserAppService _userAppService;
        private readonly BacklogAppService _backlogAppService;

        public BacklogController(IUserAppService userAppService, BacklogAppService backlogAppService)
        {
            _userAppService = userAppService;
            _backlogAppService = backlogAppService;
        }

        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            var backlogItems = (await _backlogAppService.GetBackLogItems()).Items;

            var model = new BacklogListViewModel
            {
                BacklogItems = backlogItems
            };

            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost] // Postback
        public async Task<IActionResult> Upload_Image(IFormFile file)
        {
            if (file == null || file.Length == 0) return Content("file not selected");

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

The web app runs, but when I click on the upload button, it says that:

> the necessary authorizations are not granted. At least one of these permissions must be granted: Users

Where am I doing it wrong? Otherwise, is there a simpler way to implement a file upload on ASP.NET Boilerplate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are injecting `IUserAppService` and [its implementation](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/6644dd8cc247ea8786187a3c04ea5b894142e7c0/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Application/Users/UserAppService.cs) requires `PermissionNames.Pages_Users`:

```cs
[AbpAuthorize(PermissionNames.Pages_Users)]
public class UserAppService : AsyncCrudAppService<...>, IUserAppService
```

These are your options:

1. Remove the injection of `IUserAppService` from `BacklogController`, since you are not using it.

   ```
   // private readonly IUserAppService _userAppService;
   private readonly BacklogAppService _backlogAppService;

   // public BacklogController(IUserAppService userAppService, BacklogAppService backlogAppService)
   public BacklogController(BacklogAppService backlogAppService)
   {
       // _userAppService = userAppService;
       _backlogAppService = backlogAppService;
   }
   ```
2. Log in as tenant admin, which has `PermissionNames.Pages_Users` granted by default.
3. Grant `PermissionNames.Pages_Users` to the user that you have logged in to.